Swagger Fails to Load
I'm Using Azure Functions (Isolated) and trying to navigate to Swagger UI and getting the following error:
Failed to load API definition.
Fetch error
undefined https://localhost:7009/api/v1/swagger.json
After hours of investigation I've isolated the issue to the fact that my response model contains a property which implements ICollection<T>. It seems that when the Swagger Gen reflection attempts to get the underlying type it is unable to interpret ICollection<T> as an array type.

The following a simple illustration of the issue using the OpenApi attributes bearing it mind the "OpenApiResponseWithBody" is the attribute responsible for describing the response model.
[Function("GetConnector")]
[OpenApiOperation("GetConnector", AppConst.FunctionTags.Connectors, Summary = "Get an existing Connector.")]
[OpenApiParameter("id", Type = typeof(Guid), In = ParameterLocation.Path, Required = true, Summary = "Specifies the id of the Connector to get.")]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(HttpStatusCode.OK, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json, typeof(ConnectorResponse), Description = "Returns the details of the Connector.")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> GetConnectorAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "connectors/{id}")] HttpRequestData httpReq,
    Guid id,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // omitted not important
}

ConnectorResponse object:
public class ConnectorResponse(Guid id, string name)
{
    public Guid Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = id;
    
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = name;
    
    public AuthConfigCollection AuthConfigurations
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = [];
}

AuthConfigConnection is what's causing the issue.  It's causing an issue soley because it implements ICollection<T>.
public class AuthConfigCollection() : ICollection<AuthConfigurationDto>
{
private List<AuthConfigurationDto> configs = new List<AuthConfigurationDto>();

public IEnumerator<AuthConfigurationDto> GetEnumerator()
{
    return configs.GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}

public void Add(AuthConfigurationDto item)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void Clear()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public bool Contains(AuthConfigurationDto item)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void CopyTo(AuthConfigurationDto[] array, int arrayIndex)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public bool Remove(AuthConfigurationDto item)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public int Count
{
    get;
}

public bool IsReadOnly
{
    get;
}
}

If you change the response model to following (which is NOT what I described above) then it works, but it is NOT why I described.
public class ConnectorResponse(Guid id, string name)
    {
        public Guid Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        } = id;
        
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        } = name;
        
        public List<AuthConfigurationDto> AuthConfigurations
        {
            get;
            set;
        } = [];
    }

I am asking very specifically why Swagger Gen isn't working with ICollection.  I'm not asking if it will work with List<T>, clearly during my investigation of this issue I tested List<T> vs ICollection<T>.
If I had a flat tire, it's not feasible to ask if could try switching to a different gasoline type.  I'm trying to understand WHY Swagger Gen has an issue with ICollection<T> so I don't have to go and rework a ton of models.

Please share your .csproj and startup/program.cs file

It has nothing to do with startup or csproj.  If you trying returning ICollection as part of the [OpenApiResponseWithBody] attribute the entire Swagger generation fails as shown.

are you using ISchemaFilter in your project?

No. The answer from below is pretty an entire end to end example but he's using List vs ICollection.  It's the ICollection which blows it up.

I have made few changes to the below mentioned files and got expected response.
GetConnector-
using _78600033.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace _78600033
{
    public class GetConnector
    {
        [Function("GetConnector")]
        [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "GetConnector", tags: new[] { "Connectors" }, Summary = "Get an existing Connector.")]
        [OpenApiParameter(name: "id", In = ParameterLocation.Path, Required = true, Type = typeof(Guid), Summary = "Specifies the id of the Connector to get.")]
        [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: MediaTypeNames.Application.Json, bodyType: typeof(ConnectorResponse), Description = "Returns the details of the Connector.")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> GetConnectorAsync(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "connectors/{id}")] HttpRequestData httpReq,
        Guid id,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            //creating a dummy response
            var connector = new ConnectorResponse(id, "Example Connector")
            {
                AuthConfigurations = new List<AuthConfigurationDto>
                {
                    new AuthConfigurationDto { Type = "OAuth", Config = "OAuthConfigDetails" },
                    new AuthConfigurationDto { Type = "API Key", Config = "ApiKeyDetails" }
                }
            };

            var response = httpReq.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(connector);

            return response;
        }
    }
}

AuthConfigCollection-
using _78600033.Models;
using System.Collections;

namespace _78600033
{
    public class AuthConfigCollection : ICollection<AuthConfigurationDto>
    {
        private List<AuthConfigurationDto> configs = new List<AuthConfigurationDto>();

        public IEnumerator<AuthConfigurationDto> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return configs.GetEnumerator();
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
        public void Add(AuthConfigurationDto item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
            }

            configs.Add(item);
        }
        public void Clear()
        {
            configs.Clear();
        }
        public bool Contains(AuthConfigurationDto item)
        {
            return configs.Contains(item);
        }
        public void CopyTo(AuthConfigurationDto[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            configs.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }
        public bool Remove(AuthConfigurationDto item)
        {
            return configs.Remove(item);
        }
        public int Count => configs.Count;
        public bool IsReadOnly => false;
    }
}

ConnectorResponse-
Use List<AuthConfigurationDto> AuthConfigurations instead of AuthConfigurations in  ConnectorResponse file.
using _78600033.Models;

namespace _78600033
{
    public class ConnectorResponse
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<AuthConfigurationDto> AuthConfigurations { get; set; } = new List<AuthConfigurationDto>();

        public ConnectorResponse(Guid id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}

Program.cs-
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

.csproj-
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_78600033</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="2.0.0-preview2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.3-preview2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.6.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Using the given code, I am able to access the Swagger UI page successfully.



Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5801 Commit hash: N/A +5ac2f097******ea9ef68ff (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.34.1.22669

[2024-06-12T08:52:11.303Z] Found C:\Users\*****\repos\78600033\78600033\78600033.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-06-12T08:52:16.113Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 15152) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-06-12T08:52:16.157Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        GetConnector: [GET] http://localhost:7175/api/connectors/{id}

        RenderOAuth2Redirect: [GET] http://localhost:7175/api/oauth2-redirect.html

        RenderOpenApiDocument: [GET] http://localhost:7175/api/openapi/{version}.{extension}

        RenderSwaggerDocument: [GET] http://localhost:7175/api/swagger.{extension}

        RenderSwaggerUI: [GET] http://localhost:7175/api/swagger/ui

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-06-12T08:52:21.270Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000BF6D1ED5'.
[2024-06-12T08:52:37.375Z] Executing 'Functions.RenderSwaggerUI' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=b43b9a2c-0021-4841-be41-0304378dd477)
[2024-06-12T08:52:37.721Z] SwaggerUI page was requested.
[2024-06-12T08:52:38.031Z] Executed 'Functions.RenderSwaggerUI' (Succeeded, Id=b43b9a2c-0021-4841-be41-0304378dd477, Duration=675ms)
[2024-06-12T08:52:38.186Z] Executing 'Functions.RenderSwaggerDocument' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=a9dfe31d-d362-465c-a22c-4d201e46a185)
[2024-06-12T08:52:38.216Z] swagger.json was requested.
[2024-06-12T08:52:40.904Z] Executed 'Functions.RenderSwaggerDocument' (Succeeded, Id=a9dfe31d-d362-465c-a22c-4d201e46a185, Duration=2719ms)
[2024-06-12T08:55:04.973Z] Executing 'Functions.GetConnector' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=bacfcce3-b5f1-431f-a4ae-5e132635ff18)
[2024-06-12T08:55:05.025Z] Executed 'Functions.GetConnector' (Succeeded, Id=bacfcce3-b5f1-431f-a4ae-5e132635ff18, Duration=52ms)


If you change the property AuthConfigurations of your ConnectorResponse model to be AuthConfigCollection, which is implementing ICollection, you will reproduce the error.  I get that I can use List but why is ICollection not acceptable for the swagger generator.

I am getting expected response by using public List<AuthConfigurationDto> AuthConfigCollection { get; set; } = new List<AuthConfigurationDto>(); in ConnectorResponse

Why aren't you using ICollection as I stated in the issue?  Change your ConnectorResponse model's AuthConfigurations property to be the AuthConfigCollection class.  Then you will see it bomb out.  List does not reproduce the issue.

Can you share the complete code of your ConnectorResponse Model

I have changed it to List<AuthConfigurationDto> AuthConfigCollection { get; set; } = new List<AuthConfigurationDto>(); in ConnectorResponse model, it still works for me. Currently in my code I am using List AuthConfigCollection { get; set; }, it worked too

Why do you keep using List????  It's baffling to me when I specifically call out ICollection instead.  Can you please read the updated posting.

please refer this github issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/issues/588 reported for same issue which you are facing currently for Icollection which is Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Yep. This is the issue.  This particular PR has been open for almost 2 years : https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/pull/499
Thanks for digging up and finding this thread!

@Mike can you please add your inputs in that reported issue to get a latest update on it from product team
